# gn: Unresolved dependencies

Tags: chromium, gn

I'm attempting to build Chromium on Ubuntu 22.04.  I've cloned the git repo, checked out the 102.0.5005.59 branch, added the depot_tools directory to `PATH`, and run

```bash
fetch --nohooks chromium
./build/install-build-deps.sh --no-chromeos-fonts
./build/install-build-deps-android.sh --no-chromeos-fonts
gclient runhooks
```

I then attempted to generate the ninja files by running `gn args out/Default` and setting

```
is_debug = false
is_clang = true
symbol_level = 2
dcheck_always_on = false
is_component_build = false
target_os = "android"
target_cpu = "arm64"
blink_symbol_level = 0
v8_symbol_level = 0
ignore_elf32_limitations = true
```

as the build parameters.  However, this failed with

```
Generating files...
ERROR Unresolved dependencies.
//third_party/androidx:androidx_test_espresso_espresso_contrib_java__classes(//build/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm64)
  needs //third_party/android_deps:com_google_android_apps_common_testing_accessibility_framework_accessibility_test_framework_java(//build/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm64)
//third_party/androidx:androidx_test_espresso_espresso_contrib_java__classes__assetres(//build/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm64)
  needs //third_party/android_deps:com_google_android_apps_common_testing_accessibility_framework_accessibility_test_framework_java__assetres(//build/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm64)
//third_party/androidx:androidx_test_espresso_espresso_contrib_java__classes__build_config_crbug_908819(//build/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm64)
  needs //third_party/android_deps:com_google_android_apps_common_testing_accessibility_framework_accessibility_test_framework_java__build_config_crbug_908819(//build/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm64)
//third_party/androidx:androidx_test_espresso_espresso_contrib_java__classes__dex(//build/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm64)
  needs //third_party/android_deps:com_google_android_apps_common_testing_accessibility_framework_accessibility_test_framework_java__header(//build/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm64)
//third_party/androidx:androidx_test_espresso_espresso_contrib_java__classes__dex(//build/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm64)
  needs //third_party/android_deps:com_google_android_apps_common_testing_accessibility_framework_accessibility_test_framework_java__impl(//build/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm64)
//third_party/androidx:androidx_test_espresso_espresso_contrib_java__classes__header(//build/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm64)
  needs //third_party/android_deps:com_google_android_apps_common_testing_accessibility_framework_accessibility_test_framework_java__header(//build/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm64)
//third_party/androidx:androidx_test_espresso_espresso_contrib_java__classes__process_host(//build/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm64)
  needs //third_party/android_deps:com_google_android_apps_common_testing_accessibility_framework_accessibility_test_framework_java__impl(//build/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm64)
//third_party/webrtc_overrides:webrtc_component(//build/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm)
  needs //third_party/webrtc/rtc_base:rtc_base_approved(//build/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm)
//third_party/webrtc_overrides:webrtc_component(//build/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm64)
  needs //third_party/webrtc/rtc_base:rtc_base_approved(//build/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm64)
//third_party/webrtc_overrides:webrtc_component(//build/toolchain/linux:clang_x64)
  needs //third_party/webrtc/rtc_base:rtc_base_approved(//build/toolchain/linux:clang_x64)
```

What's weird is, if I do the same with the 103.0.5060.22 branch, then everything works perfectly.  What am I missing?

Comment: Did you run `glient sync` too? It will fetch all the third-party libraries required for that specific version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you missed to pull all the third-party dependencies needed for Chromium to compile. You should run the following command after checking out or switching to another branch/version/tag of Chromium as each branch/version/tag could have different versions of third-party dependencies:

```
gclient sync
```

Now start the compilation process